# How do you get multiple variable values to output as a table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

so I'm going to jump right into the problem I'm trying to solve.

I have a MySQL table called `groups` with columns `GROUP_ID`, `GROUP_PARENT_ID`, `NAME`

where `GROUP_PARENT_ID` can be NULL.

What I want to do is write a PROCEDURE where I can input the GROUP_ID of a distant child group and get all the parent groups.

For example, if I have

```
GROUP ID    |   GROUP_PARENT_ID   |   NAME
1           |   NULL              |   Group One
2           |   1                 |   Group Two
3           |   2                 |   Group Three
```

and if I `CALL getGroupParent(3)`, I want to get the chain of groups, i.e `3,2,1` as the output

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS some_schema.getGroupParent;
CREATE DEFINER =`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getGroupParent`(
  IN childGroupID INT(10)
)
  BEGIN
    SELECT GROUP_PARENT_ID
    FROM groups
    WHERE GROUP_ID = childGroupID
    INTO @currentGroup;

    WHILE (NOT ISNULL(@currentGroup)) DO
      SELECT GROUP_PARENT_ID
      FROM groups
      WHERE GROUP_ID = @currentGroup
      INTO @newGroup;
      SET @currentGroup = @newGroup;
    END WHILE;

    SELECT @currentGroup;

  END;
```

^ Something like that, except I want all the groups the procedure went through.

Comment: What would the desired result look like

Comment: I'm not to particular about it. It can be in the form of columns, or in the form of one array in a cell of a table. Anything is fine!

All I want to get is 3,2,1 as the output in the case I specified above!

Comment: I will bang this out for you. give me a bit

Comment: Did you find a solution @Drew?

Comment: I did. I am going to do one of those Ask Your Own Questiion / Attach you own Answers to it. Will make more sense

Comment: Link me to it when you're done :) @Drew